# How to get a layer when tapped?

Tags: objective-c, ios5, core-animation, xcode4.3, calayer

I have multiple CA Layers in my view and I want to get a specific layer to perform some tasks on it..like delete with animation.
All I get using the hitTest method is a CGPoint of that location.
Now I am stuck at this point that how can I get the location of the layer which was tapped, so I can perform certain action on it.

Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done this for UIView, But try the same for CALayer.

```
 for(CALayer *layer in [self.view subviews]){
    if([layer class]==NSClassFromString(@"CALayer")){
        if([layer hitTest: location]){
            NSLog(@"you have clicked the layer in the point location");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

call CALayer::hitTest

/* Returns the farthest descendant of the layer containing point 'p'.
 * Siblings are searched in top-to-bottom order. 'p' is defined to be
 * in the coordinate space of the receiver's nearest ancestor that
 * isn't a CATransformLayer (transform layers don't have a 2D
 * coordinate space in which the point could be specified). */

- (CALayer *)hitTest:(CGPoint)p;

---

e.g. in the hosting UIView:

```
touchesEnded:(NSSet*)ts {
   UITouch *touch = ts.anyObject;
   CALayer *hit = [self.layer hitTest:touch.location]; 
}
```